# PHP Make Mobile Verification Field

Tags: php, html

I'm making a form where I have a input field for mobile number, but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. The PHP code gets the IP and gets the country code and then makes a list of options to select from.  The countries code, flag and names are in a array:

```
<?php
$countries array();
$countries[] = array("code"=>"AF","name"=>"Afghanistan","d_code"=>"+93", "img"=>"https://checkmobi.com/static/images/flags/AF-32.png");
$countries[] = array("code"=>"AL","name"=>"Albania","d_code"=>"+355", "img"=>"https://checkmobi.com/static/images/flags/AL-32.png");
$countries[] = array("code"=>"DZ","name"=>"Algeria","d_code"=>"+213", "img"=>"https://checkmobi.com/static/images/flags/DZ-32.png");
$countries[] = array("code"=>"AS","name"=>"American Samoa","d_code"=>"+1", "img"=>"https://checkmobi.com/static/images/flags/AS-32.png");
$countries[] = array("code"=>"AD","name"=>"Andorra","d_code"=>"+376", "img"=>"https://checkmobi.com/static/images/flags/AD-32.png");
.
.
.
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$json = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}");
$details = json_decode($json);
$country_code = $details->country;

echo '<select name="mobile_verification">';
foreach ($countries as $country){
echo '<option value="'.$country['d_code'].'">'.$country['name'].'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
?>
```

So, this is a sample of code, what I want is to replicate something like this https://www.cognalys.com/# Click on "Web Demo", the mobile number field that is here. I want to show flags, then the input field with auto filling of the dial code. Any guidance or anything would help.

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What do you mean by not working correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are creating the countries array properly, try this instead:

```
$countries = array(
  array("code"=>"AF","name"=>"Afghanistan","d_code"=>"+93", "img"=>"https://checkmobi.com/static/images/flags/AF-32.png"),
  array("code"=>"AL","name"=>"Albania","d_code"=>"+355", "img"=>"https://checkmobi.com/static/images/flags/AL-32.png"),
  array("code"=>"DZ","name"=>"Algeria","d_code"=>"+213", "img"=>"https://checkmobi.com/static/images/flags/DZ-32.png"),
  array("code"=>"AS","name"=>"American Samoa","d_code"=>"+1", "img"=>"https://checkmobi.com/static/images/flags/AS-32.png"),
  array("code"=>"AD","name"=>"Andorra","d_code"=>"+376", "img"=>"https://checkmobi.com/static/images/flags/AD-32.png")
);
```

Comment: The issue is not creating the array, the array is working fine. It's more about the form that the visitors will see, i want the form to be made similar to what the site I link  has, a country flag, their code and so.

Comment: The form is entirely HTML and CSS based, so you can make it look however you want through that. What is your issue/question specifically? Or are you just asking how to duplicate what you see on  someone else's site? Because at that point you should be able to just right click->view source or inspect it and see how they created it.

Comment: I tried doing that but I can't seem to figure it out, i'm not very good in html/css